# Django-rest-auth and AWS - Error 401

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-auth

In my DRF application I've used package Django-rest-auth for authentication by JWT.
In local environment everything works: I'm logging in and obtaining a token. Token has added to request's header and data has got.
But after deployment on AWS when I try to login and I get a correct token (I guess) when I add him into header I get an error 401.
Somebody know how to repair it?

**views.py**

```
from django.db.models import Count

from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework.response import Response

from .models import Task
from .serializers import TaskSerializer, TaskCreateSerializer
from .filters import TaskFilter

class TaskViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )
    renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer,)
    filterset_class = TaskFilter

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Task.objects.all()\
            .select_related('owner')\
            .only('name', 'owner__username', 'content', 'finished', 'start')

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            return TaskCreateSerializer
        else:
            return TaskSerializer

    @action(methods=['GET'], detail=False)
    def dates(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = self.get_queryset()\
            .extra(select={'start': 'Date(start)'})\
            .values('start')\
            .annotate(tasks=Count('start'))
        return Response(qs, 200)
```

**settings.py**

```
"""
Django settings for MyToDo project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.0.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os
import datetime

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '<enter-your-secret-key-here>'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    # Third party packages
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'django_filters',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'rest_auth',
    'rest_auth.registration',
    # 'rest_framework_cache',

    # For development
    'debug_toolbar',

    # My app
    'tasks',
    'users',
]

SITE_ID = 1

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',

    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'MyToDo.urls'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
INTERNAL_IPS = '127.0.0.1:8000'

# CORS
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

# REST FRAMEWORK

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': (
        'django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DATETIME_FORMAT': "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S",
}

# REST AUTH
OLD_PASSWORD_FIELD_ENABLED = True

REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
    'USER_DETAILS_SERIALIZER': 'users.serializers.UserSerializer',
}

# JWT OPTIONS
REST_USE_JWT = True

JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_encode_handler',

    'JWT_DECODE_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_decode_handler',

    'JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_payload_handler',

    'JWT_PAYLOAD_GET_USER_ID_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_get_user_id_from_payload_handler',

    'JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_response_payload_handler',

    'JWT_SECRET_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
    'JWT_GET_USER_SECRET_KEY': None,
    'JWT_PUBLIC_KEY': None,
    'JWT_PRIVATE_KEY': None,
    'JWT_ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'JWT_VERIFY': True,
    'JWT_VERIFY_EXPIRATION': True,
    'JWT_LEEWAY': 0,
    'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(days=7),
    'JWT_AUDIENCE': None,
    'JWT_ISSUER': None,

    'JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH': True,
    'JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(days=7),

    'JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX': 'JWT',
    'JWT_AUTH_COOKIE': None,

}


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'MyToDo.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

if 'RDS_DB_NAME' in os.environ:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
            'USER': os.environ['RDS_USERNAME'],
            'PASSWORD': os.environ['RDS_PASSWORD'],
            'HOST': os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
            'PORT': os.environ['RDS_PORT'],
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
            'NAME': 'localtask',
            'USER': 'localtask',
            'PASSWORD': 'localtask',
            'HOST': 'localhost',
            'PORT': '',
        }
    }

# Cache

CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": "redis://127.0.0.1:6379",
        "OPTIONS": {
            "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",
        }
    }
}

# REST Cache

REST_FRAMEWORK_CACHE = {
    'DEFAULT_CACHE_BACKEND': 'default',
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "www", "static")
```

**python.config**

```
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "MyToDo.settings"
    PYTHONPATH: "$PYTHONPATH"
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: "MyToDo/wsgi.py"
    StaticFiles: "/static/=www/static/"

packages:
  yum:
    postgresql95-devel: []

container_commands:

  01_makemigrations:
    command: "python manage.py makemigrations users tasks"
    leader_only: true

  02_migrate:
    command: "python manage.py migrate"
    leader_only: true

  03_collectstatic:
    command: "python manage.py collectstatic --noinput"

  04_createsu:
    command: "python manage.py create_user <username> <password> <email> <1 - if superuser>"
```

Comment: How do you add the auth header when testing AWS?

Comment: I've added header in Postman during tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that the server does not allow authorization header.

Try to add this to your container commands:

```
 01_wsgipass:
     command: 'echo "WSGIPassAuthorization On" >> ../wsgi.conf'
```